# Why the for loop in javascript doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
div{
   border: 1px solid black;
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
}

</style>
<script>
window.onload = function(){
var divv = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
   for(i=0; i<divv.length; i++){
      divv[i].onclick = function(){
        alert(i);
   }

   }

}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my code. I want to show the user the index of the `div` they are clicking everytime they click the div, but every time I click different div, it alert the same value which is 3

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
function myClickHandler(i) {
    alert(i);
}

window.onload = function(){
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    divs[i].onclick = myClickHandler(i);
}
```